# Fragment not receiving arguments set

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I'm trying to pass data over to a fragment from an activity. However, the fragment does not seem to be receiving the data at all.

Here is where i bundle the data:

```
        R.id.nav_chart -> {
            val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
            if (currentUser != null) {
                val completed : List<String> = getProgress()

                var basics = 0
                var loops = 0
                var functions = 0

                completed.forEach {
                    if (it == "Data Type" || it == "Operation" || it == "Condition" || it == "Null Safety") {
                        basics++
                    } else if (it == "For" || it == "Break" || it == "Repeat" || it == "When" || it == "While") {
                        loops++
                    } else if (it == "Call" || it == "Main" || it == "Recursion" || it == "Single Expression") {
                        functions++
                    }
                }

                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putDouble("basics",basics.toDouble())
                bundle.putDouble("loops",loops.toDouble())
                bundle.putDouble("functions",functions.toDouble())
                chartFragment(bundle)

            }
```

Here is where I load the fragment:

```
fun chartFragment(bundle: Bundle){
    this.setTitle(R.string.navigation_drawer_chart)
    val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val fragment = ChartFragment()
    fragment.setArguments(bundle)
    transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout1, fragment)
    transaction.commit()
}
```

Here is the fragment's `onCreate` view :

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chart, container, false)
    val graph = view?.findViewById(R.id.graph) as GraphView
    val basics = arguments!!.getDouble("basics")
    val loops = arguments!!.getDouble("loops")
    val functions  = arguments!!.getDouble("functions")

    val series = BarGraphSeries(arrayOf(
            DataPoint(1.0, basics),
            DataPoint(2.0, loops),
            DataPoint(3.0, functions)
    ))

    graph.addSeries(series)
    series.spacing = 5
    series.setValuesOnTopColor(R.color.green)

    return view
}
```

Here is where I get my data to bundle :

```
/**
 * For firebase database
 * Read user progress from db
 */
private fun getProgress() : List<String> {
    val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()?.uid
    val completed = mutableListOf<String>()

    val rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    val progressRef = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid!!).child("Progress")
    val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot:DataSnapshot) {
            for(dSnapshot : DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for(ds : DataSnapshot in dSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    val key = ds.getKey() as String
                    completed.add(key)
                    Log.d(TAG2, key)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(@NonNull databaseError : DatabaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG2, databaseError.getMessage())
        }
    }
    progressRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    return completed
}
```

I'm guessing that there is an error in the way I bundle the data or some sequencing is wrong. There is definitely data returning from the data base as my logcat shows this when `getProgress()`is executed:

[image]

Comment: How much "data" (dataset size) are you trying to include in the bundle?

Comment: @MarkKeen no more than 13 strings, of which are listed in the `for each` loop

Comment: couple things, put some break points in especially this line `val completed  = arguments?.getStringArrayList("completed")` to make sure it is being hit.  Also why are you passing the `ArrayList` and not just 3 `Double` values - this is all the `Fragment` requires, based on provided code?

Comment: @MarkKeen you are absolutely right, I changed it now to pass doubles only as seen above. When setting the break points, it hits `val basics = arguments!!.getDouble("basics"),val loops = arguments!!.getDouble("loops"),val functions  = arguments!!.getDouble("functions")` and I see that the values assigned to them are always `0.0`. I added the method as to where I get my data to bundle to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after making `val completed = mutableListOf<String>()` under `getProgress()` global instead of inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`replace `completed?` with

```
completed.forEach {

}
```

because the result it's not null-able.

---

Or try to use `putParcelableArrayList` and cast the result when you receive it to ArrayList

```
val completed: ArrayList<String> = arguments?.getgetParcelableArrayList("completed") as ArrayList<String>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried and replacing `completed?` but it does not work. Regarding `putParcelableArrayList`, how would the syntax be ? Currently it is `bundle.putStringArrayList("completed",completed)` , but when I try  chaniging it to `putParcelableArrayList` it keeps showing an error, is it because `String` does not implement the `Pardelable` interface ?

Comment: Ok, i guess the problem might be in instantiating the fragment, check this url:
https://gunhansancar.com/best-practice-to-instantiate-fragments-with-arguments-in-android/